# Error: can't chdir to 'app' when using docker start container

Tags: python, docker, flask, dockerfile, gunicorn

I have build a simple Flask app and I am trying to run it on Docker but I get this error when starting the container: `Error: can't chdir to 'app'`

The app runs fine when i start it from cmd but when I try to start the docker container for the image i created it gives the above error.

Here is the Docker file:

```
FROM python:3.6.12-alpine
COPY requirements.txt /
RUN pip3 install -r /requirements.txt

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN chmod 777 /app

ENTRYPOINT ["./gunicorn.sh"]
```

I am trying to run it with gunicorn web server. In my requirements file i have flask and gunicorn and for the python app I have just one file and here is the code:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
return 'Hello, World!'
```

I am doing the following steps to build the image and container:

1. docker build -t flask .
2. docker run -d -p 80:80 flask
3. docker start -ai (id of the container)
4. I get the error that I mentioned -> Error: can't chdir to 'app'

Can someone give me an ideea why the container is not starting and it is giving me this error? Thanks

Comment: what is directory/file tree of current folder (`.`)?

Comment: C:\flask\Example\app

Comment: is Dockerfile inside `C:\flask\Example` or `C:\flask\Example\app`?

Comment: C:\flask\Example\app

Comment: the problem inside `gunicorn.sh`. Can you share it (and project files tree desirable)?

Comment: #!/bin/sh
gunicorn --chdir app app:app -w 2 --threads 2 -b 0.0.0.0:80

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to [change directory](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#chdir). `--chdir app` parameter is unnecessary. Because you already inside `/app` directory (Do you remember `WORKDIR /app` inside `Dockerfile`?).

In other way you may change directory (if default will not work) to current work directory by using `--chdir /app` or `--chdir .`

Just change it to

```
#!/bin/sh

gunicorn app:app -w 2 --threads 2 -b 0.0.0.0:80

# OR

gunicorn --chdir /app app:app -w 2 --threads 2 -b 0.0.0.0:80

# OR

gunicorn --chdir . app:app -w 2 --threads 2 -b 0.0.0.0:80
```

`RUN chmod 777 /app` also unnecessary

Comment: Thanks I tried the first option for gunicorn.sh and it works. Thanks a lot